# Perl failed to run on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, perl

I have a simple Perl script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "###################################\n";
```

But when I try to execute it from the command line, I always see:

```
[root@testbox001 tmp]# ./def
-bash: ./def: Permission denied
```

The script is executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    88 Dec 22 01:42 def
```

Also the bash and shebang:

```
[root@testbox001 tmp]# ls -l /usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1150560 Jun 20  2022 /usr/bin/bash
[root@testbox001 tmp]# ls -l /usr/bin/perl
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 12752 Jan 17  2023 /usr/bin/perl
[root@testbox001 tmp]#
```

What are the causes?

I can only run it explicitly:

```
[root@testbox001 tmp]# /usr/bin/perl def
#########################################################
[root@testbox001 tmp]#
```

Comment: Are you on the `/tmp` volume? `/tmp` is often mounted `noexec`, preventing programs on it from being executed.

Comment: Whats `head -n 1 ./def`?

Comment: Can you try `cp -p def $HOME/home-def; $HOME/home-def` ?

Comment: @Philippe thanks. after copy to home, it work. should be due to /tmp noexec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program is found on the `/tmp` volume, which is mounted `noexec`.

```
$ mount | grep 'on /tmp '
/dev/sda3 on /tmp type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered)
```

This prevents programs on that volume from being executed.

```
$ /bin/echo foo
foo

$ cp /bin/echo /tmp/

$ /tmp/echo foo
-bash: /tmp/echo: Permission denied
```

The goal is to help neuter attacks.